# How i can make webbrowser give my only one action when document is completely loaded?

Tags: vb.net, vba, browser

like the title said :D 
How i can make webbrowser give my only one action when document is completely loaded ?

I want to make a label with how many refresh/visited sites i do .. and if i put 
label1.text = label1.text + 1 at the webbroser document complete it gives me a lot ...

( sorry for my bad english )

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowser gives you a DocumentCompleted even for each resource it loads (images, css, js, html, etc).  So you will need to **check the event parameter** and see if the url that has completed is the one you wanted to count.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA I would do it this way:

```
Dim ieApp As Object

Dim myURL As String
myURL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ieApp.Navigate myURL
ieApp.Visible = True

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ieApp.ReadyState = 4   'which equals to READYSTATE_COMPLETE

MsgBox "Loading completed"
```